# How can I convert this javascript class to something react can use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

```
const Component = require('../Component')

class PlayerComponent extends Component {
    constructor(uid, username){
        super('PlayerComponent');
        this.username = username;
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}

module.exports = PlayerComponent;
```

This is in a folder called shared that I want to use on the server and the client, right now it's working fine on the server but I can't seem to figure out how to transpile the whole shared folder so I can also use it on the client.

Comment: You need to provide more background info. What is this Component class you're using on the server for? Is it anything to do with React, or part of a different system?

Generally with React you only use the React.Component class for UI components, both on server and client. Usage of classes for other purposes, like value objects, isn't really part of best practice React.

Comment: It's not for a react component, it's for my game engine. I'm just trying to use the shared code on the front end, not necessarily as a react component but I want to be able to use the react imports so I can access the components in react code.

Comment: If you have your frontend environment setup properly you should just be able to import from the shared folder normally. E.g. `import PlayerComponent from '../../shared/PlayerComponent'`. Bear in mind that we don't use these sorts of class based value objects in React at all, either in UI components or state/data management code so you might find it of limited utility. Otherwise sharing code between backend/frontend is a good idea :thumbs-up:

Answer (score -1):

You should inherit from React.Component on the client.